# Which one is the right meaning?

Tags: meaning

I'm translating a book.
From the sentence

> 'Pale skin was seen attractive in a woman.'

Which one is the right meaning?

1. A woman who had pale skin was seen attractive.
2. Someone who had pale skin was seen attractive to a woman.

How can I handle '**in a woman**'?

Waiting for the reason & explanation.

Comment: ... Was seen ***to be*** attractive...  Or ... seen ***as*** attractive...

Comment: Women who have pale skin were considered attractive.

Comment: Thx a lot. Is there no possibility to be translated as number 2?

Comment: None at all....

Comment: You should make your comment an answer, @Drew. The other answers here are subpar.

Comment: 'Pale skin was seen as being attractive in a woman.' = 'Pale skin was seen as being an attractive attribute for a woman to possess.'

Comment: @miltonaut: Done.

Comment: As Especially Lime mentions, the sentence as given is ungrammatical. It would need to have an "as" between "seen" and "attractive".

Comment: Ah, how to handle a woman?  That's the age-old question!

Comment: @HotLicks I think the OP's question had included a preposition which might make matters more of a practical, physicality issue :O :D.

Answer (score 2):

(Per @miltonaut, I'm making my comment into an answer (but with no reference).)

It means this: *Women who have pale skin were considered attractive.*

Comment: Better answer I believe.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, it means that women who had pale skin were seen attractive.

It might make more sense if you add in some words to make the sentence the following:

> Pale skin was seen *as an attractive quality* in a woman.

The phrase *in a woman* is just qualifying the sentence by saying that pale skin is seen as an attractive quality in women in general.

Comment: Sorry all, I realise that the erroneous 'only' is a bit ambiguous so I've removed it. I hope it still makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

'*Pale skin was seen as something to make a woman look more attractive*'.

'In a woman' - ......to make a woman/women.....

I neither agree nor disagree with this statement.

I believe the downvoters are offended by the basic supposition, which has nothing to do with the translation of an already stated sentence!

Answer (score 0):

First off, the sentence given is ungrammatical and should be "Pale skin was seen as attractive in a woman."

Where you have a passive verb like "was seen", the person or people doing the seeing can be indicated with the word "by", or left unspecified. So if the sentence was "pale skin was seen as attractive by women", that would be meaning 2: "women saw pale skin as attractive". But in the sentence you give the people doing the seeing aren't specified, so the sentence means "[people] saw pale skin as attractive in a woman", meaning 1.

Answer (score -3):

*Pale skin was seen [as] attractive in a woman.*

The sentence means: A woman is attractive because of her pale skin.